# Share Site via local webserver

Tags: macos, webserver

I have a local webserver running on my machine (Mavericks). How can others on my network view the page that I'm hosting?

Comment: Please add the webserver (apache?) and its config to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Terminal and run `hostname`. If your web server is running on a non-standard port (you'd access it by, for example, localhost:8000), you'll need to use that port when connecting to it, but otherwise you should be able to just type in e.g. myhostname.local.

If this works on your computer but not another one on the same network, it means your network is set up to prohibit connections like the one you're looking for, and you'll have to look at your router for a way to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to find the IP address assigned to your computer by your local network. This is found in the Network section of System Preferences. Other people can access your local webserver by typing that IP address into their browser.

Comment: IP doesn't seem to be doing it. :(

Comment: Are you running the server from the /Library/WebServer directory or from somewhere else?

Comment: i switched the directory to my Sites folder.

Comment: I believe that this will work. http://youripaddresshere/~username

Comment: nada with that either.